# Displaying message on Ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following piece of javascript which passes data to my database and then returns a success message.

At the moment on success the button fades out and hides perfectly as it should, but the success message doesn't display.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form.user_status').submit(function () {
        var userna = $(this).find("[name='userna']").val();
        var joborder_id = $(this).find("[name='joborder_id']").val();
        var user_email = $(this).find("[name='user_email']").val();
        var app_status = $(this).find("[name='app_status']").val();
        // ...
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "user_status.php",
            data: {
                userna: userna,
                joborder_id: joborder_id,
                user_email: user_email,
                app_status: app_status
            },
            success: function () {
                $('form.user_status').hide(function () {
                    $('div.success').fadeOut();
                });
                success = 'Status changed';
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

the html where the success message should be dsplayed

```
<div class="success" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: You need to post the full relevant code. That snippet does not show what you describe in your question.

Comment: ^ exactly. post the ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually do anything with the success string.

Why not go:

```
success: function(data){
    $('form.user_status').hide();
    $('div.success').html('Status changed').delay(1000).fadeOut();
}
```

**UNLESS**
Your success div is inside your form. If so then your div will disappear immediately with the form. Which is a bit silly.
Note I've added data - you need to pass what you've returned (or how will you use the data if you wanted to?)

Display none means by default obviously your div is invisible. fadeout is just going to keep it invisible surely?

Edit: So I have removed a bunch of stuff. If you are just looking to change what is written in the div then make it disappear. You insert html then fadeout and it'll take care of it for you.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agcq7d69/)

Delay is there to give the user a second to read it.

Comment: Thanks I made the changes i actually noticed the display none after i posted it on here and changed that.  My php code just returns a echo "status Changed"; but nothing shows still the buttons fade out etc but no message

Comment: Ah I see. My mistake you've put it in a .hide.
I will amend my code as the success status changed should really be outside of it.

Comment: Hi, I use this method and it work, but If I make another operation then not showing again if not refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, ajax method has success method called when ajax response succeed. As ajax is asynchronous, after executing $.ajax, the compilation cursor moves to next line. Whatever code you write in success method will gets executed immediately after ajax success. you need to change DOM in success method, not a variable.